# Build the UnitexNet dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to build the [Unitex-Core](https://github.com/UnitexGramLab/unitex-core) DLL to use the API in a .NET application.

I tried from two way : 
 - The [ReadMe file](https://github.com/UnitexGramLab/unitex-core/tree/master/UnitexNet) indicate to build de UnitexNet project. There is no sln file so I open the UnitexNet.vcxproj  file and I try to build it. There is a lot of c++ errors (manage by the source code).

- In the [Build](https://github.com/UnitexGramLab/unitex-core/tree/master/build) repository there is many sln files. I open and build successfully the 2015 (and tried with 2013 too) library part so I can find the DLLs files in the repository. But when I want to add the reference, there is the error "Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I tried somes fixes (as regsvr32 which failed) on the error but I am not sure to have the error for good reason...

Comment: Just download the Unitex/GramLab installer from e.g. http://releases.unitexgramlab.org/3.1/win64/Unitex-GramLab-3.1_win64-setup.exe and install it. In the location it installs to will be valid 32bit/64bit C++ .NET DLLs that you should be able to copy into your project, add then a reference to.

Comment: The program is a java application, wich contains only jar lib in the repo Unitex-GramLab\App\lib.

Comment: its a makefile, so you'll need to build it on the command line. if tried [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/commandline/wsl/about) and that failed, I'm just trying [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) now

Comment: Correction: I see the UnitexNet folder now, just installing the C++ workload into my vs2017

Comment: I was able to build the `UnitexToolAndLib_vs2015.sln` C++ DLL from under the /build folder, no luck yet with UnitexNet though

Comment: OK I'm down to linker errors. Using the Platform Toolset `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)` compiles but won't link. You'll need the relevant Windows SDK installed (7.0, I think) and to add the paths it installs to your `Library Directories` in your `VC++ Directories` setting under the `UnitexNet Property Pages`